# How can I use linebreaks in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This piece of code gives error:

```
var test = '1
2
3
4';
```

What if I want to nicely structure a code in javascript, like this:

```
var return = '
<div>
   content
</div>
';
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Do you merely want the string *declaration* to be multiline so that the code is readable, or do you also want the string *contents* to be multiline so that the string is readable when it is displayed as output?

Comment: @apsillers If the string is used to hold HTML, that might not matter (though in some cases it's a valid question)

Comment: Please consider that this is a duplicate before adding yet another answer.

Comment: @JasonC often, I think everyone's writing their answer simultaneously. When answer #6 starts writing, there are still no actual answers posted just yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't possible to span lines like you have described.

If you use the `+` operator and close your strings you can do something like this:

```
var retVal = '<div>' +
                'content' +
             '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code throws an error is because Javascript uses [automatic semicolon insertion](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons)

If you want to structure a large string in multiple lines you are better off doing something like this -:

```
var returnValue = '<div>' + 
                  'content' + 
                  '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to write multi line JavaScript you can use `\` or if you want line breaks you can use `\n`.

So something like this for multi-line:

```
var returnVal = '<div> \
                  content \
              </div>';
```

or if you want line breaks in the output of the string:

```
var reutrnVal = '<div> \n   content\n </div>'
```

or you can concatenate using '+':

```
var returnVal = '<div>' + 
'   content' + 
'</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

<del>JavaScript doesn't allow literal line breaks in strings.</del> (Looks like that's wrong; see [stackErr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18239360/105570), for example.) There are two semi-reasonable approaches: use the `+` operator (as others have suggested), or put your lines in array and then call `join('\n')` on the array:

```
var return = [
  '<div>',
  '  content',
  '</div>'
].join('\n');
```

The latter isn't really efficient, but that probably won't matter in most cases.

If you find you're doing this a lot (assembling many little HTML snippets programmatically), it would be worth looking into a template library such as [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/).

Answer (score 0):

If you end a line with a `\`, then your string can continue on the next line.

```
var return = '\
<div>\
   content\
</div>\
';
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice trick for creating multi-line strings in JavaScript which don't involve escaping the line feeds for every line, described at http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/05/multi-line-strings-in-javascript-and.html. Basically, you'd define a function with only a comment containing the multi-line string you want, call `toString` on that function and strip out the comment, like in this example below:

```
var html = (function () {/*
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
*/}).toString().match(/[^]*\/\*([^]*)\*\/\}$/)[1];
```